# Table value function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column in a table with sample data as follows:

```
ServiceTypeIds 
 7,1 
 1,9 
 1
 9
 4
 7
 7
```

In my Where clause I use the following to search on it:

```
WHERE(@ServiceTypes IS NULL OR CHARINDEX(','+CAST(SEP.ServiceTypeIDs as VARCHAR(255))+',', ','+@ServiceTypes+',') > 0)))
```

If my param @ServieTypes equals '1,9', then I get results, but when it's @ServiceTypes = '1' or just '9', then I don't recieve anything back. The table design is pretty poor but I just dont have enough time to create new table and modify the c# code too. I tried to use a Table Value function but since the ServiceTypeIds is not the primary key column, it didnt work.  Anyone could help with this?

Comment: you might have some spaces, try to retrieve results using `LIKE`

Comment: There are no spaces in the column, also no spaces are in the paramter

Comment: Change the positions of arguments in CHARINDEX. `CHARINDEX(','+@ServiceTypes+',', ','+CAST(SEP.ServiceTypeIDs as VARCHAR(255))+',')`  [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Comment: your statement does not compile

Comment: I am running these statements and results are ok. `SELECT CHARINDEX(','+'1'+',', ','+'1,9'+',')`  `SELECT CHARINDEX(','+'9'+',', ','+'1,9'+',')`. You just change the position of arguments in `CHARINDEX` function of your statement. Put `','+@ServiceTypes+','` as 1st argument.

Comment: okay i changed it, if i pass '1' it gets a row, if i pass '1,9' it fetches rows but if i pass just '9' it does not retrieve rows

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14605/discussion-between-tammy-and-bjan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the positions of arguments for `CHARINDEX` i.e. Put `','+@ServiceTypes+','` as 1st argument and other as second